# Define linespacing using a Point-Value

Tags: latex, tex, spacing, miktex

i have to write a paper where the chair claims a font size of 12pt AND a line-spacing of 15pt (which seems not to be \onehalfspacing).

Can anyone tell me how to define the spacing using the value 15pt?

Best regards and thanks!
Philipp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the line spacing exactly by altering the `\baselineskip` value.

```
\setlength{\baselineskip}{15pt}
```

Note that you have to use this command inside the `document` environment in order for it to have an effect.

Comment: i tried it in my preamble and it seemed to have no effect. after you recommendation i tried it outside the preambel and THERE it surprisingly works.

Comment: @Philipp:  Hey, good.  I edited out the preamble part in my answer.  Also, I'm not sure how explictly setting \baselineskip interacts with, e.g, automatic font size changes in section headings.  I think section headings include their own spacing info so that should be okay, but you may want to check to confirm spacing is appropriate for section headings or any areas in document where where you're explicitly changing font size.